# can not load i18n assets file while hosting on IIS

Tags: angular5, angular2-routing, angular6

**Update**

I added json in MIME type in IIS and it worked in Chrome but in IE, it is going to  `"http://localhost:8080/Advisoryportal"` which is fine but immediately redirected to `"http://localhost:8080/"` which is giving HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found and going to `http://localhost:8080/Default.asp`.

Can some one please help in this?

===========================================================================

I have a small application i am working on and I can host it on IIS but en.json is not getting loaded and hence I am not able to support multilingual text.I am getting 404 errro.I tried many solutions which I can find over internet.

```
"http://localhost:8080/Advisoryportal/assets/i18n/en.json", ok: false,
```

**WebPackVersion:webpack@4.8.3**

**Package.json**

```
"assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets/",
              "src/assets/i18n",
              "src/web.config",
              "src/loan-insurance-overview",
              "src/assets/i18n/en.json"
            ],
```

**Module.ts**

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient,"./assets/i18n/", ".json");
}
```

[image]

Comment: So your IIS website is mapped to dist folder? Also, check you have json MIME type added in IIS

Comment: I added that MIME sometime back and it worked,was about to update the answer.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was fixed after adding application/json MIME type in IIS